# Deep Link in Push Notification is always redirecting to App Store

Tags: ios, swift

I seem to have no control over how the Deep Link in Push Notifications is always sending me to the App Store, even after the App is opened when I tap on the Push Notification. I already have a handler for my Push Notification and it catches the url:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
extension Coordinating: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if let apsDict = response.notification.request.content.userInfo["rpr_url"] as? String {
            if apsDict.fullURLPathString().contains(string: "myurlPath") {
                Coordinating.sharedInstance.customFunction()
            }
        }
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

The delegate for this is set as well, I also have the didReceiveRemoteNotification handled:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        customHandler.handle(application, userInfo: userInfo, fetchCompletionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        customHandler.handle(application, userInfo: userInfo, fetchCompletionHandler: nil)
    }
```

I am currently using Repro's Push Notification Service. I have also tried disabling/enabling and adding breakpoints to all URL handlers. Where does this redirect bit of code come from?

Edit: the app-site-association file is also handling Deep Links, so no problems when clicking on the url from E-mails and Browsers. This seems to only be happening for Push Notifications.

Comment: did you add first part of deep link url to your info.plist file ?

Comment: @ZahraAsgharzade Do you mean the scheme for the Deep Link url into the Info.plist's URL Types?

Comment: @ZahraAsgharzade I added the first part of my deep link Url to my Info.plist now, it's under URL types -> Item 0 -> URL Schemes -> Deep Link scheme. It's still redirecting me to the App Store, though